# Good C++11 information, other than Wikipedia?

Tags: c++, c++11

Does anyone know a good website where I can find information on C++11, other than Wikipedia?

Comment: What do you mean by a "C++0x website"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best I know is [ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG21 - The C++ Standards Committee](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/) where the [n3092.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf) document is available.

Answer (score 7):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp

Great wiki for C++ information.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the Visual Studio Team Blogs. They discuss quite heavily the new features in C++0x, which are in VS2010, and how they can be used.

Comment: Use your favourite Web search engine! A collection of good posts is available on Visual C++ Team (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/) also C++ Next (http://cpp-next.com/) is worth reading.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/04/22/decltype-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-3.aspx

Comment: VC++2010 does not have support for all  features defined in C++0x, it's probably less than half the features defined in C++0x.

Comment: Your point being? They are references about C++0x features in a major compiler. The OP didn't spec what he was using.

Comment: My point is obvious, your comment is miss leading because that resource only covers just 4 features (since VC++2010 supports only a small amount of C++0x features).

Answer (score 1):

I use this one a lot: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

Comment: Someone didn't like my link :(